# Is it possible to create an interface that is cast compatible with particular hidden api interface in Java?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, interface, java-me

I develop mobile applications (Android, J2ME), and wonder if following steps are feasible:

1. Assume that an application has to run on J2ME enabled platform
2. The platform contains some platform-specific API like NokiaUI on Nokia handsets. Some classes included in the API implements interfaces that are also included within the API.
3. Platform manufacturer delivers complete javadoc for the API, along with an emulator, and classpath libraries. All definitions of interfaces included in the API are known because of their presence in the javadoc.
4. Create a new J2ME project, and **do not include** platform-specific optional packages, so imports from packages are impossible to do.
5. Select random interface (eg. SomeInterface) from the platform-specific API and create its exact definition inside the project. Package for the interface has to be named exactly like the selected interface package.
6. Assume that the interface definition is:

   ```
   public interface SomeInterface
   {
       public void someMethod();
   }
   ```
7. Select a class that implements the interface, and instantiate it using newInstance() method.
8. Cast instantiated object to SomeInterface.
9. Call someMethod() on the interface.

Is it all possible, or ClassCastException will occur on cast ?

Comment: If this was for *regular* Java, the answer to this is "yes". I do not work with J2ME (or Dalvik) though :( Good luck. It might be best/easiest to just **Try It And See** -- if it *doesn't work*, then analyze the situation and, if needed, post *another* SO question with the situation and what error conditions occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Midp installer on some phones (for example Nokia Symbian) will not install the applications that have classes with the same package and class name as the platform classes.

If you are trying this to create compatability between different platforms then you just need to create two versions of the application where one ships your own version of the classes and the other that uses them from platform.

If your intent is to override platform classes that is not possible on midp.

Comment: I see. Basing on Your answer I have one more question - how to prepare a library, that contains a definition of interface I would use (compatible with platform specific one)? I mean the library is only needed to avoid compiler complaints, but finally I don't want its content to be included into JAR. I think of library like android.jar in Android SDK, where all classes are fully compatible with platform classes, but every method in these classes is just a dummy method without body. All in all: how to make custom class-path like library, that enables you to use hidden or platform specific api?